# Magento 2 - Need to filter comma seprated values in addAttributeToFilter along with category filter

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

I need to filter comma sperated values in addAttributeToFilter in magento 2

Here is my Code:

```
$comma_separated_values = 26,27,28,29;

$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')->addAttributeToFilter('color', $comma_separated_values);
```

How I can pass in this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$categoryProducts = $category
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in',$comma_separated_values));
```

If you want to add category filter along with other collection just add this:

```
->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categories))
```

Where `$categories` would be like `$categories= '123,321';`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Need to do same for 
$cat_id = 26,28;
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($cat_id);

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Need to pass in load: $cat_id = 26,28;

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($cat_id);


In this: -----------
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in',$colorvalues));

Comment: Magento wont allow to load two category at a time, you can add category filter for multiple categories but you can't load with multiple categories

Comment: Can you please update my code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, I have updated my answer what is possible, but load two categories at a time is not possible :)